# Very simple jQuery attribute question

Tags: jquery

Either I have misunderstood [the jQuery docs for .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), or I'm making a very stupid error.

Why isn't this working?

```
<div id="mydiv" title="mytitle"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var username = $("#mydiv").attr("title");
    alert(username);
});
</script>
```

I just get 'undefined' in the alert.

Comment: This particular example is just fine. Are you sure you don't have other elements with `id="mydiv"` on the page, which might confuse jquery ?

Comment: Yes - sorry - it was another jQuery problem in the page, that Firebug hadn't spotted an error. Sorry everyone :(

Comment: Don't be sorry for asking the question, probably helped you investigate further and find the real issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/6NG4P/

Are there any other alerts on the page that may be causing the issue or is it possible the library isn't loading correctly (like `$` has a conflict) or there is another `div` with the same `id` without a `title` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

What you have works, [you can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/szDdG/), make sure you don't have *another* `id="mydiv"` element earlier in the page - it's both invalid HTML and *usually* the result will be `$("#mydiv")` finding the *first* occurrence, which may not have that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[Your code works fine for me as it looks fine](http://jsbin.com/ihudu4)

It is probable that surrounding code is doing something wrong.

Make sure that:

- You have loaded the jquery library in the page
- There is not conflict if you are using some other library